# How to store a variable so that it can't be modified?

Tags: java

Sorry if I get the format of this question wrong, it is my first post.

Essentially my problem is that I assign an object as a variable, I then change the original object and then try and use the variable to restore the object back to its original conditions. However, I constantly find, despite never calling a method on the variable that the variable itself has changed to be exactly the same as whatever the object now looks like.

The object that I try to store is b and the variables which are seemingly changed are both store and original. I call methods on original but none should change it, just recieve information from it. I call no methods on store.

How, when I try to perform b = store; could I ensure that b becomes the same as the b passed to it in the parameters?

The code for the method is here:

```
public int getMove(Board b, int playerNum) throws QuitGameException{        
    original = b;
    store = b;
    int otherPlayerNum = 0;
    try{
        out.println("In house 2 on our side " + original.getSeeds(2, playerNum));
    } catch (Exception e){
        out.println("problem");
    }
    try{
        out.println("In house 2 on our side " + store.getSeeds(2, playerNum));
    } catch (Exception e){
        out.println("problem");
    }


    //Prints the current board to the user in a textual interface
    if(playerNum == 1){
        otherPlayerNum = 2;
    } else {
        otherPlayerNum = 1;
    }

    out.println("Opponent's side: ");
    for(int i=6;i>0;i--){
        try{
            out.print("House " + i + " : [" + original.getSeeds(i, otherPlayerNum)+ "] ");
        } catch (InvalidHouseException e){
            out.print("Invalid house");
        }
    }
    out.println();
    out.println("Opponent's score: " + original.getScore(otherPlayerNum));

    out.println("Computer's side: ");
    for(int i=1;i<7;i++){
        try{
            out.print("House " + i + " : [" + original.getSeeds(i, playerNum) + "] ");
        } catch (InvalidHouseException e){
            out.print("Invalid house");
        }
    }
    out.println();
    out.println("Computer's score: " + original.getScore(playerNum));

    //Each move is tried so that the score can be received, the move which produces the highest score is chosen to be returned.
    System.out.println(b.toString());
    int highestScore = b.getScore(playerNum);
    int bestHouse = 0;
    boolean moveFound = false;
    int move = 1;
    int score = 0;
    for(int i =1; i<7 ;i++){
        try{
            b.makeMove(i,playerNum);
            score = b.getScore(playerNum);
        } catch (Exception e){
            out.println("a problem");
            score = 0;
        }

        if(score>highestScore){
            bestHouse = i;
            highestScore = score;
            moveFound = true;
            move = i;
        }
        try{
            System.out.println("Seeds in side " + playerNum + " and house " +i+" = "+original.getSeeds(i, playerNum));
        } catch (Exception e){
            out.println("problem");
        }            
        b = original;
    }
    try{
        out.println("In house 2 on our side " + original.getSeeds(2, playerNum));
    } catch (Exception e){
        out.println("problem");
    }
    try{
        out.println("In house 2 on our side " + store.getSeeds(2, playerNum));
    } catch (Exception e){
        out.println("problem");
    }
    out.println("All okay? "+b.equals(store));
    out.println("All okay? "+original.equals(store));
    int side = playerNum;
    int bestScore = 0;
    int seeds = 0;

    //If no move has been found which increases the score then the first house with a seed in it is chosen to be returned
    if(!moveFound){
        for (int i =1; i<7 ;i++){
            try{
                seeds = original.getSeeds(i,playerNum);
                System.out.println("Seeds = "+ seeds);
                if (seeds>0 && !moveFound){
                    move = i;
                    moveFound = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                seeds = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return move;

}
```

Thank you in advance. I would be happy to provide further details.

Comment: can you use final somehow?

Comment: Ever heard about ***[`final`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) variable***.

Comment: If I were to assign store as final would it mean that nothing I did to it would change it? Just because I need store to become equal to b at the start of the method and then after that point never change. Can you make something final? Or does it always have to be final?

Comment: That's the sole purpose of final

Comment: Why would you call b = store when you called store = b earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables don't hold objects. They hold *references* (or pointers, if you prefer) to objects. Assigning an object to a variable doesn't create any copy of the object. It simply make the variable point to this object:

```
Board b = new Board();
```

This creates a Board objects, and make the `b` variable point to this object:

```
                b ------> board object

Board store = b;
```

This assigns the same board object to another variable `store`. So both `b` and `store`now point to the board object.

```
                b ------> board object
                             ^
                store -------|
```

So if you naw do something like `b.setName("new name")`, you modify the state of the board object, and since `b` and store both reference the same board object, calling `store.getName()` will return the new name:

```
                b ------> board object with new name
                             ^
                store -------|
```

If you want a variable to hold the original board state, you need to create a copy of the board object:

```
Board store = new Board(b);
```

This constructor should copy everything from the board it takes as argument:

```
public Board(Board other) {
    this.name = other.getName();
    ...
}
```